# Javascript web3js frontend

Tags: javascript, html, solidity, web3js

I'm currently writing a SmartContract. So far I've written this contract:

pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract SmartContractEnergy {

```
struct EnContract {
    uint price;
    uint amount;
    string energysource;
    address owner;
}

EnContract[] public encontracts;

mapping (uint => address) public contractToOwner;
mapping (address => uint) public ownerContractCount;

function _createContract(uint _price, uint _amount, string _energysource) internal {
    uint id = encontracts.push(EnContract(_price, _amount, _energysource, msg.sender)) - 1;
    contractToOwner[id] = msg.sender;
    ownerContractCount[msg.sender]++;
}

function createContract(uint _price, uint _amount, string _energysource) public {
    require(ownerContractCount[msg.sender] == 0);
    _createContract(_price, _amount, _energysource);
}
}
```

For test purposes I want to have a html file that simply creates a contract on a local blockchain (I'm using Ganache for my development). That's how my html looks like currently. I'm using web3 1.0

```js
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545');

var abi = [myABI];
var contractAddress = 'myAddress';
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);
```

```html
<h3>Web3 — Usage Example</h3>
<div class=”tab-content”>
  <div role=”tabpanel” class=”tab-pane active” id=”blockchain”>
    <h3> 1. Set the value in the blockchain</h3>
    <div class=”form-group form-inline”>
      <input type=”text” class=”text form-control” value="price">
      <input type=”text” class=”text form-control” value="amount">
      <input type=”text” class=”text form-control” value="energysource">
      <button class=”set btn btn-primary”>Set Value</button>
    </div>
    <h3> 2. Get the current value</h3>
    <div class=”form-group”>
      <div>
        current value is <span class=”value”></span>
      </div>
      <button class=”get btn btn-primary”>Get Value</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So how can I now transfer my data to the blockchain and also read it out of the blockchain? I would like to use implement the solution in Javascript (No JQuery if possible).

Answer (score 0):

You already have `web3` imported so the first thing would be to deploy your contract. Your call does not deploy a new contract instance, it is trying to load an existent one. After that you just have to call your methods with the parameters you want to store. On the documentation of `web3` there are examples of how to do that. Take a look at [this](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send).